# while文を付け加えたい

Tags: python

ここに１＜＝X＜＝８９(大吉、大大大吉ではないとき)にくじ引きを繰り返すwhile文を付け加えたいです。
どこにどのように付け加えれば良いのでしょうか。

```
import random
x=random.randint(1,99)

z=int(input('1を入力してください。おみくじを開始します。'))
if z==2:
  print('１を入力してください。')
else:
  if x < 10:
    print('出た数字',x,'は凶でした。')
  if 9 < x < 30:
    print('出た数字',x,'は末吉でした。')
  if 29 < x < 50:
    print('出た数字',x,'は吉でした。')
  if 49 < x < 70:
    print('出た数字',x,'は小吉でした。')
  if 69 < x < 90:
    print('出た数字',x,'は中吉でした。')
  if 89 < x < 99:
    print('出た数字',x,'は大吉でした。')
  if x == 99:
    print('出た数字',x,'は大大大吉でした。')
```

Comment: 「どこにどのように付け加えれば良いのでしょうか。」とのことですが、質問者さんがどこから繰り返したいのかにも依るかと思います。また、少し気になったのですがzが2以外のとき(例えば3)はスルーで良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

全体を`while`で囲み`break`で`while`を抜けることが可能です。

```py
import random

while True:
    x=random.randint(1,99)
    z=int(input('1を入力してください。おみくじを開始します。'))
    if z==2:
      print('１を入力してください。')
    else:
      if x < 10:
        print('出た数字',x,'は凶でした。')
      if 9 < x < 30:
        print('出た数字',x,'は末吉でした。')
      if 29 < x < 50:
        print('出た数字',x,'は吉でした。')
      if 49 < x < 70:
        print('出た数字',x,'は小吉でした。')
      if 69 < x < 90:
        print('出た数字',x,'は中吉でした。')
      if 89 < x < 99:
        print('出た数字',x,'は大吉でした。')
        break
      if x == 99:
        print('出た数字',x,'は大大大吉でした。')
        break
```

Comment: 他の方のコメントの通り`z==2`のところは`z != 1`の方がいいかもしれません。

Comment: この回答ですとランダム取得が一度しか行われないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ほんとでした。修正しました。